# Qt Creator crashes when opening project

Tags: c++, qt, crash

Hi i have a problem with Qt,and I were finding solution on google but without any results.
In recent days Qt creator behaves strangelly, when I open Qt projects by: "File->open projects" and openfiledialog is appeared,saddenly windows gives me such message:
http://www.picz.ge/img/s1/1309/22/b/b73648160a97.png

But when i run Qt creator as an Administrator,it behaves normally without any crashes or something like that.

I looked at event log and what I see is that:
http://www.picz.ge/img/s1/1309/22/6/6eaebfa8e584.png

Tried reinstalling Qt but doesn't work.

Comment: I have similar issues with all Qt Creator version  higher than 3.4.0 (or 3.5 I could not test 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have corrupted Qt Creator settings files. Close all Qt Creator instances and remove / temporarily rename all Qt files from %APPDATA%/Roaming. Also try to remove / rename ProjectName.pro.user -file from the project directory.

Comment: Tried everything but still the same. it crashes :(

Comment: The same problem. Tried everything but it didn't help.